# I tried running my code in android studio but whenever i click on the button it crashes

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, button

I tried clicking on the button on my code but the application keeps on crashing i want to know if my code is wrong or my device used for running is wrong.here is the code

```
package com.example.pnrcompanion;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        TextView text1=findViewById(R.id.txt_signup2);
        TextView text2=findViewById(R.id.txt_3);
        Button btn1=findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class));
            }
        });

        text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });

        text2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ForgetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });




    }
}
```

I want to try to fix this code so that i can run it for my project.

Comment: You need to review the error message from your log file. If you aren't able to figure out the issue from that, post it here.

Comment: Check the Logcat and find the exception that's getting thrown. It's not possible to tell what's wrong with the code you posted without seeing the error message and the stacktrace.

Comment: there is no error in the logcat thou, the program ran smoothly but when i tried clicking the button the app crashes

Comment: What is the error on your logcat? Please edit and put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a bit difficult to tell what's going on because you have multiple onClick listeners (two for Textviews). Each one is bringing you to a specific Class/XML layout so anything in the XML layout or the code for those classes could be causing the crash.

If it's crashing when you click on btn1 then I would check the ProfileActivity.java or its corresponding XML file.

Start your program with the debugger which is the little green icon in the top right (over from the run options) and then go click the button that's crashing it. If you open up your logcat (and ensure it's showing errors) you should see something there. That'll give you more of an idea of what's going on.